# How to handle URL relative/absolute "glitch" in contenteditable when copy and pasting

Tags: anchor, contenteditable, relative-path, absolute-path, clipboard-interaction

In `contenteditable` regions, if you paste an element with a URL attribute, *in some browsers* it converts the URL from **relative** to **absolute**.

I've read through some bug reports that claim it's "fixed" in the latest release, but it's not.

I threw together this fiddle to demonstrate: **[Hurray for Demos!](http://jsfiddle.net/xtVY6/)**

It's there, it's ugly, and I'm wondering what is the best way to fix it.

1. The 1st idea that comes to mind is `onpaste`, find all `anchors` in the current node and `parse it with regex`. Not ideal I suppose, but it might be effective.
2. ???
3. ???

*I really wish they'd just leave things alone and not create so many browser related issues with `contenteditable`, **but I guess that would make it too easy**.*

Any thoughts on the best way to address this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CKEditor, before letting browser break the data, copies all `src`, `name` and `href` attributes to `data-cke-saved-src|href` attributes. Unfortunately, since data is a string, it has to be done by regexp. You can find the code here: [/core/htmldataprocessor.js#L772-L783](https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-dev/blob/de36349/core/htmldataprocessor.js#L772-L783).

```
var protectElementRegex = /<(a|area|img|input|source)\b([^>]*)>/gi,
    // Be greedy while looking for protected attributes. This will let us avoid an unfortunate
    // situation when "nested attributes", which may appear valid, are also protected.
    // I.e. if we consider the following HTML:
    //
    //  <img data-x="&lt;a href=&quot;X&quot;" />
    //
    // then the "non-greedy match" returns:
    //
    //  'href' => '&quot;X&quot;' // It's wrong! Href is not an attribute of <img>.
    //
    // while greedy match returns:
    //
    //  'data-x' => '&lt;a href=&quot;X&quot;'
    //
    // which, can be easily filtered out (#11508).
    protectAttributeRegex = /([\w-]+)\s*=\s*(?:(?:"[^"]*")|(?:'[^']*')|(?:[^ "'>]+))/gi,
    protectAttributeNameRegex = /^(href|src|name)$/i;

function protectAttributes( html ) {
    return html.replace( protectElementRegex, function( element, tag, attributes ) {
        return '<' + tag + attributes.replace( protectAttributeRegex, function( fullAttr, attrName ) {
            // Avoid corrupting the inline event attributes (#7243).
            // We should not rewrite the existed protected attributes, e.g. clipboard content from editor. (#5218)
            if ( protectAttributeNameRegex.test( attrName ) && attributes.indexOf( 'data-cke-saved-' + attrName ) == -1 )
                return ' data-cke-saved-' + fullAttr + ' data-cke-' + CKEDITOR.rnd + '-' + fullAttr;

            return fullAttr;
        } ) + '>';
    } );
}
```

Then, while processing HTML taken from editable element, `data-cke-saved-*` attributes override the original ones.

Comment: Eesh, that's quite a work-around. Interesting approach though. I built a simple function that just finds the base url and removes it. Guess my approach needs work since like you say, image use `src` not `href`. Thanks for the input!

Comment: Sometimes I've got a feeling that everything CKEditor does is working-around browser bugs, quirks and inconsistencies ;).

Comment: - and an extensive list it is. I reference your editor and TinyMCE as well, but there's just so much *extra* in there that it turns me away (same goes for nearly every 3rd party software/plugin). Developing from scratch.. it's been educational to say the least :)

Comment: Khem... :D Working on CKEditor for more two years I indeed learnt a loooot. One of the things is that I should never try to write from scratch anything production-ready with contenteditable... But, good luck! :)

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a browser bug that's not specific to `contenteditable`: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=805359

That issue was opened 10 years ago and last updated 6 years ago. Yet it's still open.

You can see the bug here on StackOverflow. Inspecting any SO link shows that the href value is a relative URL. Copying it and pasting it as HTML has the relative link rewritten into an absolute URL.

Example:

[image]

[image]